# Group by along with columns external to the clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a SQL table as follows

```
    id    |date_accessed     
----------+------------
     1    | 16/10/2014
     1    | 28/10/2014
     1    | 25/11/2014
     1    | 16/12/2014
     2    | 30/09/2014
     2    | 03/10/2014
     2    | 17/10/2014
     2    | 03/01/2015
```

I need to group the data by the month and year, but I also want to know how many months since the user accessed the system for the 1st time

```
    id    |   month    |   year     |   length_in_month
----------+------------+------------+-------------------
     1    |    10      |   2014     |          1
     1    |    11      |   2014     |          2     
     1    |    12      |   2014     |          3
     2    |    09      |   2014     |          1
     2    |    10      |   2014     |          2
     2    |    01      |   2015     |          5
```

My query is as follows

```
select 
    id, 
    Extract(MONTH from "date_accessed") as month, 
    Extract(year from "date_accessed") as year 
from 
    exampleTable 
group by 
    1, 2, 3 
order by 
    1, 3, 2
```

But I do not have access to the `min(date_accessed)` when I do group by, to obtain the length of the `length_in_month` column.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: On what basis do you chose the gap to be one month when it should be zero months? shouldn't it be 0 months for `10/2014`  as it was first accessed in the same month - `16/10/2014`   ?

Comment: Ideally, this represents checking customer activity at the end of each month. So for this process, it starts with at least 1. But that is a business requirement, if I can generate the 0, adding 1 to that is a straightforward process.

Comment: why are there two october 2014 in the results?

Comment: The date is unique per ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used `AGE` function to determine the difference between start date of month of *first accessed* and end date of *actual date accessed* to give an interval that could be fairly considered as a month and  then add 1 to it, as you mentioned. This gives expected result.

`first_access` is calculated separately in a CTE as it is a single value for each id and not per id, month, year.

```
with m AS
(
select id, min(date_accessed)
                    as first_access from t
group by id
)
select t.id, Extract(MONTH from "date_accessed") as month, 
             Extract(year from  "date_accessed") as year,
            EXTRACT ( month from 
                      MIN( AGE( date_trunc('month', date_accessed) 
                                + interval '1 month - 1 day',  --last day of month
                             date_trunc('month', first_access) --first day of month
                         ))
                    ) + 1 as length_in_month
from t join m on t.id = m.id 
group by t.id,month,year 
order by 1,3,2;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=300a1049726e604a4e98f16b359657ee)

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery, as shown below:

```
SELECT 
    exampleTable.id, 
    EXTRACT(month FROM "date_accessed") AS month, 
    EXTRACT(year FROM "date_accessed") AS year,
    /* Calculate # months since the user accessed the system for the 1st time */
    (EXTRACT(year from "date_accessed") - EXTRACT(year from firstTimeAccessDatesTable.firstAccessDate)) * 12
    + (EXTRACT(month from "date_accessed") - EXTRACT(month from firstTimeAccessDatesTable.firstAccessDate)) + 1 AS length_in_month
FROM 
    /* Join exampleTable with firstTimeAccessDatesTable by id */
    exampleTable
INNER JOIN(
    /* Perform subquery to obtain the date a given user accessed the system for the first time */
    SELECT
        id,
        MIN("date_accessed") AS firstAccessDate
    FROM
        exampleTable
    GROUP BY
        1
    ) AS firstTimeAccessDatesTable
ON exampleTable.id = firstTimeAccessDatesTable.id
GROUP BY
    1, 2, 3, 4
ORDER BY
    1, 3, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need first to select Id and min(month) group by Id, so you will get the first date for each Id. 
Then another select like the one you did plus the select I suggest above.

Answer (score 0):

The query below gives you the exact duration in months. Keeping your above sample input in mind the query will give you length_in_months duration as 0 if the time difference is less than 30 days. The multiplication by -1 is to convert the negative duration to be displayed as positive values.

```
create table Test(id integer, date_accessed date);
insert into Test values(1, "2014-10-16");
insert into Test values(1, "2014-10-28");
insert into Test values(1, "2014-11-25");
insert into Test values(1, "2014-12-16");
insert into Test values(2, "2014-09-30");
insert into Test values(2, "2014-10-03");
insert into Test values(2, "2014-10-17");
insert into Test values(2, "2015-10-16");


select a.id, a.month, a.year, a.date_accessed, (timestampdiff(MONTH, 
a.date_accessed, a.min_date)) * -1 as length_in_month from (
select id, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_accessed) as MONTH, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM 
date_accessed) as YEAR, date_accessed, (select MIN(date_accessed) from Test) as 
min_date from Test order by date_accessed) a order by a.id asc;

Output
1   10  2014    2014-10-16  0
1   10  2014    2014-10-28  0
1   11  2014    2014-11-25  1
1   12  2014    2014-12-16  2
2   9   2014    2014-09-30  0
2   10  2014    2014-10-03  0
2   10  2014    2014-10-17  0
2   10  2015    2015-10-16  12
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7c833/6

```
-- drop table t;

/*
create table t as
select id, date_accessed::date
from (values
     (1, '2014-10-16'),
     (1,  '2014-10-28'),
     (1,  '2014-11-25'),
     (1,  '2014-12-16'),
     (2,  '2014-09-30'),
     (2, '2014-10-03'),
     (2, '2014-10-17'),
     (2, '2015-01-03')
) as x(id, date_accessed)
*/

with unique_months as
(
    select 
        id,

        date_trunc('month', date_accessed) as monthify
    from t 
    group by id, monthify

)
, compute_length as
(                   
    select 
        id, monthify,

        ( 
            ( 
                extract(year from monthify) - extract(year from min(monthify) over(partition by id)) 
            ) * 12 
        )
        +
        ( 
            extract(month from monthify) - extract(month from min(monthify) over(partition by id))
        )
        +
        1 as length_in_month


    from unique_months
)
select id, 
  extract(year from monthify) "year", 
  extract(month from monthify) "month",
  length_in_month
from compute_length
order by id, monthify
```

Results:

```
| id | year | month | length_in_month |
|----|------|-------|-----------------|
|  1 | 2014 |    10 |               1 |
|  1 | 2014 |    11 |               2 |
|  1 | 2014 |    12 |               3 |
|  2 | 2014 |     9 |               1 |
|  2 | 2014 |    10 |               2 |
|  2 | 2015 |     1 |               5 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7c833/2

```
-- drop table t;

/*
create table t as
select id, date_accessed::date
from (values
     (1, '2014-10-16'),
     (1,  '2014-10-28'),
     (1,  '2014-11-25'),
     (1,  '2014-12-16'),
     (2,  '2014-09-30'),
     (2, '2014-10-03'),
     (2, '2014-10-17'),
     (2, '2015-01-03')
) as x(id, date_accessed)
*/

with unique_months as
(
    select 
        id, 
        extract(year from date_accessed) "year",
        extract(month from date_accessed) "month",
        min(date_accessed) as month_representative
    from t 
    group by id, year, month

)
, compute_length as
(                   
    select 
        id, year, month,

        ( 
            ( 
                extract(year from month_representative) - extract(year from min(month_representative) over(partition by id)) 
            ) * 12 
        )
        +
        ( 
            extract(month from month_representative) - extract(month from min(month_representative) over(partition by id))
        )
        +
        1 as length_in_month


    from unique_months
)
select * 
from compute_length
order by id, year, month
```

Results:

```
| id | year | month | length_in_month |
|----|------|-------|-----------------|
|  1 | 2014 |    10 |               1 |
|  1 | 2014 |    11 |               2 |
|  1 | 2014 |    12 |               3 |
|  2 | 2014 |     9 |               1 |
|  2 | 2014 |    10 |               2 |
|  2 | 2015 |     1 |               5 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest query if Postgres has built-in DATEDIFF.

Query can be made more idiomatic by using DISTINCT ON.

DISTINCT ON is specific to Postgres. It discards duplicate rows and keeps one only, and it sort rows based on the parameter(s) passed to it.

```
-- http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff
create or replace function month_diff (start_month date, end_month date) 
returns int as $$
begin
    return (date_part('year', end_month) - date_part('year', start_month))*12 +
            date_part('month', end_month) - date_part('month', start_month);
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql' immutable;


select
    distinct on (id, date_trunc('month', date_accessed))

    id, 
    date_part('year', date_accessed) as year,
    date_part('month', date_accessed) as month,

    month_diff( min(date_accessed) over(partition by id), date_accessed ) + 1 
        as length_in_month
from t;
```

Output:

[image]